# CSS Div With Arrow Centre

Tags: css

I'm wondering how to go about creating a div with an arrow attached to the bottom pointing downwards. I can achieve that effect like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/.

However, I'm not sure how to ensure that the arrow is in the centre of the div? In the fiddle, it is positioned using:

```
left: 20px;
```

But can I dynamically set this to appear in the centre? Obviously with people viewing the page on different screen resolutions I can't know in advance the integer to put here.

Please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know how wide the arrow will be, you can do this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/1464/)):

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -20px; /* -(width/2)px */
```

Otherwise, you can use transforms with `left: 50%`:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Just to further clarify, "width" means the total width (`width + padding + border`). In this case, it's (`0 + 0 + 40`).

Answer (score 0):

What you what to do is add `left:50%;` and `margin-left:20px;`to `#mybox:after`. See http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/1470/